# Read from textfile, create number range, filter out float numbers outside the range and store the final values in text file

Tags: c#, range

I am having difficulty in creating a number range which will then filter the random float numbers stored in the text file and eventually store the numbers inside the number range. Let's say, for example, the number range to be 742.8 to 1000. I want to filter those outside this range and store the float numbers which are inside the range in the text file.

I have created a text file which has random float numbers.
I have successfully created a code that is able to read the numbers in text file.

This is the random float numbers in the text file

```
743.6 
742.8
744.7
743.2
1000
1768.6
1750
1767
1780
1500
```

This is my code(which is now able to read the above text file):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile.txt";

            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated Version:
Still could not remove the numbers from the range and store the numbers inside the range in text file.
(When compiled the all the data from the text file is removed.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)


    {

        string usersPath = "C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile.txt";

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersPath).ToList();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(usersPath);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            double x = double.Parse(line);

            if (x > 740.9 && x < 1000.8)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(line);
              //  Console.WriteLine(line);

            }
            writer.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

}

The expected result: store whatever float numbers inside the number range in a text file.

Comment: What's your issue? It looks like you just didn't write the code for the rest of your requirements

Comment: I have edited the codes already, pls take a look, at my comments and codes

Comment: Why do you call `double.Parse` on `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `line`?

Comment: I looked up on how to convert string to double, and got this example. I forgot to change that. Now i have changed that, but it still give the same result.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `x`'s value or writing to other file?

Comment: What do u mean sir?

Comment: I mean that you should debug your code (put breakpoint or log the value of `x`), to see if the issue is with check (`x` has different value that expected) or writing fails

Answer (score 0):

Here is basically what you need to do. You already have half of the work done already!

1. Before the `foreach` loop, you need to open a `StreamWriter` on `filePath` overwritting the existing file.
2. In the `foreach` loop, convert the string `line` to a `double` value (see `Convert.ToDouble`), and if it falls inside you range, write `line` to `filePath` with the `StreamWriter`.
3. Close the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: The string `line` contains one `double`. To tell whether it falls in your range of values, it needs to be converted to a `double`, and then compared to the two `double` values that are the lower and upper bounds of the range. If it is in range, `line` can be written directly to the output file since it contains the number as a string.

Comment: I have followed yr advice and created an update version. Please do check above.Thank you sir. And how do i do the comparing of two double values that are lower and upper bounds of the range.

Comment: Sadly it does not, when compiled, all the numbers from the textfile are erased.

Comment: Yes, this is because you are overwriting the input file. I thought that this was what you wanted to do "Trying to overwrite the current text file.". If you want to write to another file, specify a different path to the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: My objective is to remove the numbers outside the range and store the numbers inside the number range in the textfile

Comment: Ok, you mean the textfile is empty. Run your program in debug. You will be able to see why the line `writer.WriteLine(line);` is never executed.

Comment: How do i do that sir? sorry am a novice.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: Should i move the numbers in the range to another text file?

Comment: Yes, if this is what you want to do. Just use a different pathname for the output textfile.

Comment: The writeline function works fine. Now, the problem is it only write the top number in the text file (743.6).  It does not take in the number range.

Comment: I see. It is because `writer.Close();` closes the output file inside the `foreach` loop. The output textfile has to be closed only after the `foreach` loop has finished.

Comment: So i shall comment off that statement?

Comment: Actually, no. You have to move it outside the loop, so that the file gets closed after all lines have been processed.

Comment: Ahh right right after the close bracket for Foreach loop. I will try that and get back to u tmr

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Day 2, and still the text file is empty after compilation.